# SP2013 Newsfeed Web Part - Allow deletion of any post

Tags: 2013, newsfeed

We have a Site Feed Web Part on the homepage which displays the Newsfeed. Is there a way to allow other users, like a specific group, to be able to delete posts from other people?

My first thought was to try Site Collection Admin of the posters MySite but this does not work.

Essentially we need a safety net to remove any posts that are perhaps inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

- Go into Central Administration
- Go into Application Management
- Choose Manage Service Applications
- Highlight UserProfileServiceApplication (dont click the actual link)
- On the top of the browser click Adminstrators
- Add your user into the box and press add
- Make sure your user has Manage Social Data permission

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/8ba6f563-4c24-4729-a710-a9efd5c1649b/how-do-i-administer-peoples-newsfeed-posts